# Calling paper-toast with PHP

Tags: php, forms, polymer, toast

I am trying to show a paper-toast when the user forgets to fill in some data in a form or when he submits a wrong e-mailadres.
I have this PHP-code that will print out an error message on the screen when the user submits the form and forgets to fill in the input or when he submits a wrong e-mailadres. This works fine. Here's a small part of the code:

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($errorMsg) && $errorMsg) {
        echo "<p>*",htmlspecialchars($errorMsg),"</p>\n\n";
    }
?>
```

I want to make it so, that the error message appears in a paper-toast. Further, i want to display a paper-toast when the form is successfully submitted.

My question is: is it possible to call a paper-toast with the error message and appears when the form is submitted?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way PHP can "trigger client side events" is by outputting HTML that will behave as you want. In your case, you basically need to output the HTML for a toast and make sure it opens as soon as the page is loaded. To do that, just set the [`opened` attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-toast):

```
printf('<paper-toast text="%s" opened></paper-toast>', htmlspecialchars($errorMsg));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This seems logical. Unfortunately, i my case,  the paper-toast would not show up because my webpage will reload when the user submits the form. Momentary i am working on a Ajax request to stop the page from loading when the mail is submitted.

Comment: Uhmm, i gave it some thought. Is there a way that your answer runs after the page is reloaded? Because in that case the Ajax Request should not be necessary.

Comment: If you do this via AJAX, you should set and open your toast via Javascript. If you don't use AJAX, you just need to output the above HTML. I'm unclear what your holdup is...

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I forgot to upload an file via FTP.